# How to be notified when a global mutex is released?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, callback, mutex

I'm working on a project in which I want my ASP.NET dll to be notified when a global mutex is killed (yes, another 'use mutex for single instance') - for example using Process Explorer. If you want, a little kind of "MyMutexWatcher".

What is a reliable way to achieve this?

Rough/pseudo code is much appreciated